# How to change hostname independently of an ip address?

Tags: centos, centos-7, hostname

To change hostname of a machine (as stated here: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/centos-hostname-change/) following files must be edited:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network
HOSTNAME=node1

/etc/hosts
192.168.1.100 node1
```

Is it possible to change hostname independently of an ip address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the following file changes the hostname:

```
vi /etc/hostname
node1
```

Reboot is required.

Answer (score 1):

No need to "hard code" the IP address in `/etc/hosts`, you can just use a locally available loopback address (eg 127.0.0.1), eg see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145022

Comment: It does not work but modifying /etc/hostname file works.

Comment: If you have a local program that tries to resolve hostname `node1` when the system is offline and/or without accessing the network (for some reason), the program won't be able to resolve the hostname; hence, the suggestion to always use `files` to resolve the localhost hostname to the loopback address. (nb: you'll still have to set the hostname, you just don't do it in `/etc/hosts` ⁠— as you say, these are set "independently".)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options

```
$ sudo hostnamectl set-hostname <new_hostname>
$ sudo nmcli gen hostname <new_hostname>
$ sudo vi /etc/hostname
```

Comment: Is every single line sufficient or do I need to type all three to get the result?

Comment: Any one of the those should work.